# Remove Highchart series in shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

It is very straight forward to append a new series in R using high chart:

h1 <- Highcharts$new()
h1$chart(type...
h1$series(data = ...

However, I cannot find a way to remove the series in R once it is appended. 
Here is the api
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Can some one please show me how to use the methods in the API in R? Or anyway to remove
a series in high chart object in R?

Thank you very much for your time.

Vin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are available as a list in `h1$params`. Here is one example:

```
h1 <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()
h1$series(data = 1:3, name = "MySeries 1", color = "red")
h1$series(data = 4:6, name = "MySeries 2", color = "green")
h1
```

[image]

```
h1$params$series[[1]] <- NULL
h1
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! Somehow params is not listed under API and thus I never used it. this works like a charm.